# python3 MySQL Fetchone error

Tags: python, mysql

My Code:

```
import sys
import mysql.connector
import hashlib

#empty dict of hash :  snapshot
rowHash = dict()

#connect to destdb
dest2cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='password', host='localhost', database='destDB')
#get cursor for dest
destCur = destcnx.cursor()

#list of src datebase
srcdblist = ['src1','src2','src3','src4','src5','src6','src7','src8','src9','src10','src11','src12','src13','src14','src15','src16','src17','src18']


#Count combined row evaluated
count = 0

for srcdb in srcdblist:
    #display to console  DB access
    print("Accessing DB: " + str(srcdb))

    #connect to src db
    srccnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user2', password='password',host='otherloc',database=srcdb)
    srcCUR = srccnx.cursor()


    sql="SELECT * FROM `src_tbl` WHERE 1 ;"

    srcCUR.execute(sql)

    row = srcCUR.fetchone()

    while row:
        #hash
        hashVal = hashlib.md5(str(row).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

        #check if in rowHash Dictionary
        if hashVal in rowHash.keys():
            # if there already
            rowHash[hashVal] = rowHash[hashVal] + srcdb + '~src_tbl|'
        else:
            #failing that
            snapshotAdd =  srcdb + '~src_tbl|'
            #add to dict
            rowHash[hashVal] = snapshotAdd
            #insert into purplebox2 database set up SQL
            sql = "INSERT INTO `dest_tbl` (`item_id`,`comments`,`accessDate`,`restock`,`meta_hash`) VALUES "
            insertValues = str(row)[:-1] + ", '"+hashVal+"' )"
            sql = sql + insertValues + " ;"
            #Execute SQL
            destCur.execute(sql)

        #Count loc
        count += 1

        if (count % 500) == 0 :
            print ("viewing total :"+ str(count) + " in db "+srcdb)

        #load next row
        row = srcCUR.fetchone()

    destcnx.commit() # commit changes after each db
    srcCUR.close
    srccnx.close

print("Total count: "+str(count)+", flushing snapshots to DB")

#flush snapshots to db
flushcount = 0
for (hashtxt, snapShot) in rowHash.items():
    sql = "UPDATE `dest_tbl` SET `meta_snapshot` = '"+snapShot+"' WHERE `dest_tbl`.`meta_hash` = '"+hashtxt+"';"
    destCur.execute(sql)
    flushcount += 1
    if (count % 250) == 0:
        print("flushing : "+str(count)+" into DB")

destcnx.commit()
destCur.close()
destcnx.close()
```

After several run through in src6 through src9 it crashes giving the below error, all changes I have made to my code are scrubbing out db user details.
Any help will be very appreciated.

### Error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/PROJECT/import_dbs.py", line 69, in <module>
    row = dkCUR.fetchone()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 811, in fetchone
    row, self.description)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 403, in row_to_python
    result[i] = self._cache_field_types[field_type](row[i], field)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\conversion.py", line 430, in _INT_to_python
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'314\x044255\x1821312sSasA1'
```

Comment: I had the same problem when I was using the latest version of `mysql-connector-python` (`2.0.3`). After I downgraded it to the latest `1.x` version (`1.2.3`), the problem disappeared.